# Reading Text From PDF , Text Position Not Fix

Tags: itext

i am using iTextSharp to extract text from pdf.

The text which i am looking for has varying position and it depends on how the pdf is printed, by and large the text position is not fixed.

Can anyone give any logic how can it be done ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: What's the problem? I fail to see the question. When you extract text from a PDF with iText, you get the coordinates, don't you?

Comment: @Nilambar  I am trying to capture specific text from cms1500 form. I am using Location Extraction Strategy and By Coordinate i can able to get the desire text, But every time PDF contains different types of scaling and also shifting is there, so text which i am looking for has no fix position. Form can be large or small and margins can also vary.